# How to know Vendor ID for Ark Benefit S502Plus smartphone?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, linux-mint

In [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up) tutorial I tried to connect my smartphone with Android Studio on Linux Mint.
How I can know Vendor ID? [This](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#VendorIds) page hasn't ID for Ark.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the vender ID through the command `lsusb` to list usb buses and device details, or `discover` command

open the terminal and run:

```
lsusb
```

or:

```
discover --vendor-id --model-id usb
```